# Trying to make a batch file to launch steam offline faster

Tags: batch-file, connection, wifi, steam

I want to make a script that checks if my computer is online or not when I first login to my computer and then copies a offline or online version of a steam configuration file dependent on whether I am connected to the internet or not. Steam on it's own just takes too long to retry connections and I don't want to hit "Launch in offline mode" every time I start it up. So far I have figured out that I can get the bat to run automatically by sticking it in the windows startup folder. Now I just need to figure out if my copy code is correct and a method to detect whether I am connected to the internet or just a wifi network in general or not.

```
@Echo Off
connection=(Test Connection Here? Help?)
if connection==true (copy /y Z:\Steam\config\loginusers_online.vdf Z:\Steam\config\loginusers.vdf) else (copy /y Z:\Steam\config\loginusers_offline.vdf Z:\Steam\config\loginusers.vdf)
start Z:\Steam\steam.exe
exit
```

Haven't had to code for a while, is there a command to check if the wifi antenna is connected to just any router or would I have to ping a connection off of a website?

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims=: " %%G IN ('netsh wlan show interfaces^|findstr "State"') do set "status=%%G"`.  The variable value will be **connected** if your computer is connected to a wireless network.

Comment: Just be aware that there is a possibility that during the startup process, your script could be run before, or during, an available network connection being made. This means that it may detect that you're offline, just before you are online, and therefore not act in the manner you expected of it. Please also be aware that the comment above assumes a wireless connection has been made, it doesn't know whether it is just connected to a router, _(internal network)_, or to the internet. It also does not know whether you're connected via ethernet, _(wired)_. You could have multiple network devices.

Comment: That is fine, the device in question has no external ethernet ports to speak of. I tried setting my connection variable to the above code, but it always returns false. Am I missing something obvious, like I said I haven't had to do this for a while and forgot a lot of the nuances. Could you be more specific?